# iText PDF Rectangle fill with color

Tags: java, itext

I want to fill rectangle with color. I used these code but not working.

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
canvas.rectangle(50, 600, 500, 40);
canvas.setColorFill(BaseColor.GRAY);
//canvas.setRGBColorFill(20, 50, 30);
//canvas.setCMYKColorFill(0, 0, 0, 75);
canvas.setColorStroke(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
canvas.stroke();
```

Anyone has idea how to fill it ?

Comment: If you want to both fill and stroke a path, you have to use `canvas.fillStroke()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call canvas.fill() after setColorFill()

```
 PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
 canvas.rectangle(50, 600, 500, 40);
 canvas.setColorFill(BaseColor.GRAY);
 canvas.fill();
```

Answer (score 1):

I use iText 5 and this works for me

```
rectangle.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.YELLOW); // or whatever color you have
canvas.rectangle(rectangle);
```

Just make sure it's **not inside** `canvas.beginText()` and `canvas.endText()` or any other drawing operation.