# Itextpdf : text and color in rectangle

Tags: pdf, itext, itextpdf

Is it possible to set a text with background color in rectangle using iText?

I have the following code :

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
BaseColor bColor = new BaseColor(0xFF, 0xD0, 0x00);
canvas.setColorFill(bColor);
canvas.fill();
canvas.rectangle(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom() - 1.5f, rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
canvas.stroke();
```

But color seems to be ignored. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check solution indicated here [iText PDF Rectangle fill with color][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162628/itext-pdf-rectangle-fill-with-color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing things in the wrong order.

You need:

1. Change graphics state (e.g. fill color, stroke color,...)
2. Create path
3. Fill and/or stroke path

You can switch step 1 and 2, but step 3 always needs to be last.

So you should adapt your code like this:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
BaseColor bColor = new BaseColor(0xFF, 0xD0, 0x00);
canvas.setColorFill(bColor);
canvas.rectangle(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom() - 1.5f, rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
canvas.fillStroke();
```

Note that this is also wrong:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
BaseColor bColor = new BaseColor(0xFF, 0xD0, 0x00);
canvas.setColorFill(bColor);
canvas.rectangle(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom() - 1.5f, rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
canvas.fill();
canvas.stroke();
```

In this case, the rectangle will be filled by `canvas.fill()`, but it won't have any border, because the path created using the `rectangle()` method has been dealt with when you filled it. No new path has been created between `canvas.fill();` and `canvas.stroke();` so the `stroke()` operator won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Please put

```
canvas.setColorFill(bColor);
canvas.fill();
```

after

```
 canvas.rectangle(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom() - 1.5f, rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
```

same issue [iText PDF Rectangle fill with color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162628/itext-pdf-rectangle-fill-with-color)

Comment: If you put `canvas.fill()` after `canvas.rectangle(...)`, you will fill the rectangle, but that rectangle won't have any border. The line `canvas.stroke();` will be ignored. If you want to *fill* and *stroke* the path, you need the `fillStroke()` method. In short: your answer points in the right direction, but it solves only half of the problem ;-)