# How to set the color in IText via rgb?

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

Is it possible to set the color in IText via rgb?
I set the color this way:

```
canvas.SetFillColor(ColorConstants.BLUE);
```

I would like to set the color more accurately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Itextpdf : text and color in rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32840981/itextpdf-text-and-color-in-rectangle)

Comment: Your code sets the color for the next filing operations in that canvas. *" would like to set the color more accurately"* - what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2):

For iText7:

```
    com.itextpdf.kernel.color.Color colorBlue = new DeviceRgb(0, 0, 255);
    canvas.SetFillColor(colorBlue);
```

see [Kernal.Colors](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.8/namespacei_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_colors.html) for more information, there are numerous options there.

For iText5:
You should be able to create a new BaseColor e.g.

```
canvas.SetFillColor(new BaseColor(0,0,255));
```

[BaseColor doc](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/java/5.5.11/index.html?com/itextpdf/text/BaseColor.html)

Comment: I am working with iText 7 7.1.15 API https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.15/. There is no BaseColor object in this library.

Answer (score 0):

I understood. I need to set color for PdfLinkAnnotation using RGB. This is done like this:

```
PdfLinkAnnotation annotation = new PdfLinkAnnotation(rect);
```

annotation.SetColor(new PdfArray(new float[] { 0.5647f, 0.9334f, 0.5647f }));

Answer (score -1):

From the [IText API documentation](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.16/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_pdf_1_1_canvas_1_1_pdf_canvas.html#a7f07414323c2fc2f20e374eadfa25492): you could use `SetFillColorRgb`:

> `virtual iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.PdfCanvas iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.PdfCanvas.SetFillColorRgb(float r, float g, float b)`